# SSIS Truncation Failure

Tags: sql, ssis

I am getting this truncation error and am not sure how to fix it. The length is 4000 in input and output.

> Error: 0xC02020C5 at Data Flow Task, Data Conversion [16]: Data conversion failed while converting column "DESCRIPTION" (99) to column "Copy of DESCRIPTION" (201).  The conversion returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
>
> Error: 0xC020902A at Data Flow Task, Data Conversion [16]: The "output column "Copy of DESCRIPTION" (201)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Copy of DESCRIPTION" (201)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
>
> Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion" (16) failed with error code 0xC020902A while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (17). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: Since the error message mentions code pages I suspect your problem is related to that. Are your strings Unicode? Make sure to use the datatype DT_WSTR (unicode) instead of DT_STR.

Comment: What is your data source? Excel? A Memo field from Access? Something else? What are you attempting to do with this Description? Conver from NTEXT to DT_STR?

Comment: You say the length is 4000 in input and output, do you mean your source and destination objects?  If not, ensure that any object with 'columns' properties has the proper data type/length.

Comment: Yes source and destination is 4000. It is Oracle to SQL.

Comment: I just ignored the errors and the data is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just ignoring the error as it was not altering my data in any way.